# How to create a metafield on Shopify using API?

Tags: api, shopify, liquid

I want to create a meta field for a customer on a Shopify site when he is logged in, 
I have gone through all forums and the docs of Shopify but no success.

I found this link (http://www.shopify.com/technology/3032322-new-feature-metafields) where it can be done through API but I don't know how to use this on liquid theme. The following is an example provided on above URL:

```
<code>
product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(product_id)
product.add_metafield(ShopifyAPI::Metafield.new({
   :description => 'Author of book',
   :namespace => 'book',
   :key => 'author',
   :value => 'Kurt Vonnegut',
   :value_type => 'string'
}))
</code>
```

Please guide me on this so I can finish it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're showing is to be used within a rails app, which needs to be oauth approved by store owner to perform any action with your store data. Your visitors/customers cannot post/edit/delete metafields with pure liquid inside your x.liquid files.

Comment: ok can we do it on run time using rails app after oath approved by store owner. Is there any other way to use metafields using x.liquid files or can we use any third party integration into x.liquid files ?

Comment: Did you take a look at customer tag/s? http://docs.shopify.com/api/customer maybe this would be a faster / easier approach for you.

Comment: Yes i checked that but its not working. Can you tell me how can we get it functional & working in my shopify site using docs.shopify.com/api/customer link ? Thanks